# how to add symbols to the multiple stock data

Tags: for-loop, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

#i have **scraped** data below is my code, now i want to add a column of symbols to the respective company data, plz guide me how the symbol can be added to the respective firm data

#code below

```
from time import sleep

import pandas as pd

import os

import numpy as np

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

symbols =['FATIMA',
'SSGC',
'FCCL',
'ISL',
'KEL',
'NCL',
'DGKC',
'SNGP',
'NML',
'ENGRO',
'HUMNL',
'CHCC',
'ATRL',
'HUBC',
'ASTL',
'PIBTL',
'OGDC',
'EFERT',
'FFC',
'NCPL',
'KTML',
'PSO',
'LUCK',
'SEARL',
'KOHC',
'ABOT',
'AICL',
'HASCOL',
'PTC',
'KAPCO',
'PIOC',
'POL',
'SHEL',
'GHGL',
'HCAR',
'DCR',
'BWCL',
'MTL',
'GLAXO',
'PKGS',
'SHFA','MARI',
'ICI',
'ACPL',
'PSMC',
'SPWL',
'THALL',
'BNWM',
'EFUG',
'GADT',
'AABS']

company = 1

for ThisSymbol in symbols :
    

    # Get first symbol from the above python list
    
    company = 2

    # In the URL, make symbol as variable
    url = 'http://www.scstrade.com/stockscreening/SS_CompanySnapShotYF.aspx?symbol=' + ThisSymbol
    browser.get(url)
    sleep(2)

    # The below command will get all the contents from the url
    html = browser.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
    # So we will supply the contents to beautiful soup and we tell to consider this text as a html, with the following command
    soup = BeautifulSoup (html, "html.parser")

    for rn in range(0,9) :
        plist = []
        r = soup.find_all('tr')[rn]

        # Condition: if first row, then th, otherwise td
        if (rn==0) :
            celltag = 'th'
        else :
            celltag = 'td'

        # Now use the celltag instead of using fixed td or th
        col = r.find_all(celltag)
        print()
        if col[i] == 0:
            print ("")
        else:
            
            for i in range(0,4) :
                cell = col[i].text
                clean = cell.replace('\xa0 ', '')
                clean = clean.replace (' ', '')
                plist.append(clean)


        # If first row, create df, otherwise add to it
        if (rn == 0) :
            df = pd.DataFrame(plist)

        else :
            df2 = pd.DataFrame(plist)
            colname = 'y' + str(2019-rn)
            df[colname] = df2

    if (company == 1):
        dft = df.T
        
        # Get header Column
        head = dft.iloc[0]


        # Exclude first row from the data
        dft = dft[1:]
        dft.columns = head
        dft = dft.reset_index()

        # Assign Headers
        dft = dft.drop(['index'], axis = 'columns')
        
    else:
        dft2 = df.T
    


        # Get header Column
        head = dft2.iloc[0]

        # Exclude first row from the data
        dft2 = dft2[1:]
        dft2.columns = head
        dft2 = dft2.reset_index()

        # Assign Headers
        dft2 = dft2.drop(['index'], axis = 'columns')
        dft['Symbol'] = ThisSymbol
        
    dft = dft.append(dft2, sort=['Year','Symbol'])

    
    company = company +1
    
dft
```

Answer (score -1):

my output looks this, i want to have a symbol column to each respective firm data
Symbol,i have added

dft['Symbol'] = ThisSymbol

but it add just first company from the list to all companies data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBmI4.jpg)